# Flutter go_router: How to make changes to routes without refreshing the whole app

Tags: flutter, flutter-go-router

I just started using go_router package. I am coming from Navigator 1 where you could easily call `Navigator.push` to get a new screen on the stack. This makes development faster since all I have to do is save or hot reload to see most of my changes.

However, I have noticed that the slightest change to the routes in go_router package requires a full restart of the app. Imagine that I am trying to trouble shoot an issue 12 routes deep, every time I make a change, I have to go from the beginning of the app till I get to that screen.

Is there a better way?

A workaround I have used is to use Navigator 1 methods while building UI for fast development. But eventually, I have to swap it for go_router's method and that's where it gets tiring quickly.
I expect that if I change something (maybe add a new route of edit a pathParameter), a simple save should effect my changes

Here is my main.dart

```html
void main() {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();

  if (!BuildConfig.isDev) {
    ErrorWidget.builder = (FlutterErrorDetails details) => Container();
  }

  SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations(
      [DeviceOrientation.portraitUp, DeviceOrientation.portraitDown]).then(
    (val) {
      runApp(
        ProviderScope(
          child: MyApp(),
        ),
      );
      FlutterError.demangleStackTrace = (StackTrace stack) {
        if (stack is stack_trace.Trace) return stack.vmTrace;
        if (stack is stack_trace.Chain) return stack.toTrace().vmTrace;
        return stack;
      };
    },
  );
}

class MyApp extends ConsumerWidget {
  MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  final botToastBuilder = BotToastInit();
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context, WidgetRef ref) {
    final router = ref.watch(goRouterProvider);
    return MaterialApp.router(
      routerConfig: router,
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: BuildConfig.isDev,
      title: AppInfo.title,
      themeMode: ThemeMode.light,
      
      theme: ThemeData(
          useMaterial3: true,
          scaffoldBackgroundColor: AppColors.canvas(context),
          primarySwatch: AppInfo.appPrimarySwatch,
          textTheme: GoogleFonts.figtreeTextTheme()),
      builder: botToastBuilder,
    );
  }
}
```

Here is my config

```
final goRouterProvider = Provider<GoRouter>((ref) {
  return GoRouter(
    navigatorKey: AppGlobals.navigatorKey,
    initialLocation: RoutePath.root.path,
    observers: [BotToastNavigatorObserver()],
    redirect: (context, state) => null,
    routes: [
      GoRoute(
          path: RoutePath.root.path,
          name: RoutePath.root.name,
          builder: (context, state) => const SplashScreen(),
          routes: [
            GoRoute(
              path: RoutePath.welcome.path,
              name: RoutePath.welcome.name,
              builder: (context, state) => const WelcomeScreen(),
            ),
            GoRoute(
              path: RoutePath.enableLocation.path,
              name: RoutePath.enableLocation.name,
              builder: (context, state) => const EnableLocationServicesScreen(),
            ),
          ]),
      GoRoute(
          path: RoutePath.choices.path,
          name: RoutePath.choices.name,
          builder: (context, state) => const ChoiceScreen(),
          routes: [
            GoRoute(
              path: RoutePath.signUpPhone.path,
              name: RoutePath.signUpPhone.name,
              builder: (context, state) => const EnterPhoneNumberScreen(),
            ),
            GoRoute(
              path: RoutePath.enterPassword.path,
              name: RoutePath.enterPassword.name,
              builder: (context, state) => const CreatePasswordScreen(),
            ),
            GoRoute(
              path: RoutePath.verifyNumber.path,
              name: RoutePath.verifyNumber.name,
              builder: (context, state) {
                final isCode = state.extra ?? false;
                return VerifyPhoneScreen(
                  isCode: isCode as bool,
                );
              },
            ),
            GoRoute(
              path: RoutePath.resetPassword.path,
              name: RoutePath.resetPassword.name,
              builder: (context, state) => const ResetPasswordScreen(),
            ),
            GoRoute(
              path: RoutePath.forgotPassword.path,
              name: RoutePath.forgotPassword.name,
              builder: (context, state) => const ForgotPasswordScreen(),
            ),
            GoRoute(
              path: RoutePath.passwordSuccess.path,
              name: RoutePath.passwordSuccess.name,
              builder: (context, state) => const PasswordSuccessScreen(),
            ),
            GoRoute(
              path: RoutePath.uploadId.path,
              name: RoutePath.uploadId.name,
              builder: (context, state) => const UploadIDScreen(),
            ),
            GoRoute(
              path: RoutePath.propertyHome.path,
              name: RoutePath.propertyHome.name,
              builder: (context, state) => const CreatePasswordScreen(),
            ),
          ]),
      GoRoute(
        path: RoutePath.login.path,
        name: RoutePath.login.name,
        builder: (context, state) => const LoginScreen(),
      ),
      StatefulShellRoute.indexedStack(
          // parentNavigatorKey: shellNavKey,
          builder: (context, state, navigationShell) {
            return ScaffoldWithNestedNavigation(
              navigationShell: navigationShell,
              type: UserType.type,
            );
          },
          branches: baseBranches(AppGlobals.navigatorKey)),
    ],
  );
});
```

Comment: Hey, can you add your router config, main.dart, etc.

Comment: @OzanTaskiran I have added the main.dart and config codes.

Comment: please see my answer, this looks like  an instantiation problem.

Comment: Experiencing the same issue. Have read a lot of articles and replies, but none has helped. Hopefully, someone here will offer a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this is the problem:

```
final router = ref.watch(goRouterProvider);
```

inside your build method. If you do a change, your build method gets called again, which creates a new router. So as i see you don't need any BuildContext or special param inside your GoRouter. I would just declare it global or inside your class

```
final GoRouter _router = GoRouter(
    routes: [
      // Your GoRoutes
    ],
  );
```

and pass it to your MaterialApp.

Comment: I tried this, it still does not reflect changes unless I restart